# plyr::aaply is very slow compared to nested loops

Tags: r

I have a simple task to do. I have a 3D array (10,1350,1280) and I want to calculate the min over the first dimensions. I can do it using aaply like the following

```
minObs <- plyr::aaply(obs, c(2,3), min)  # min of observation
```

But it is extremely slow compared to when I just write a nested loop.

```
minObs<-matrix(nrow=dim(obs)[2],ncol=dim(obs)[3])

for (i in 1:dim(obs)[2]){
  for (j in 1:dim(obs)[3]){
    minObs[i,j]<-min(obs[,i,j],na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}
```

I am new to R , but I am guessing that I am doing something wrong with aaply function. And hint would be very much appreciated. How can I speed up using aaply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the base `apply` function?

```
apply(obs, c(2,3), min)
```

It's fast, doesn't require loading an additional package and gives the same result, as per:

```
all.equal(
  apply(obs, 2:3, min), 
  aaply(obs, 2:3, min), check.attributes=FALSE) 
#[1] TRUE
```

Timings using `system.time()` using a `10 x 1350 x 1280` array:

```
Loop
#   user  system elapsed 
#   3.79    0.00    3.79 

Base apply()
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.87    0.02    2.89 

plyr::aaply()
#Timing stopped at: 122.1 0.04 122.24
```

Comment: Very good point. The reason to use aaply was to make it parallel which I then understood it is not going to help me for such easy and simple functions like min. So I guess I can switch to apply. Just a quick question? what makes aaply slower than apply? only loading an additional package does not seem to cause such a big difference.

Comment: @newbie - as far as I understand it, `plyr` (which is now quite old in the world of R), was written for code cleanliness, not speed. In this particular case, it improves neither it seems.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.